# Time limited Junit @Ignore

Tags: junit

We have multiple tests and some of them sometimes, for environmental issues fail. So the test gets @Ignored. Unfortunately sometimes it stays @Ignored a long time after the environmental issue disappeared. Is there a good way of making an @Ignore valid for a period of time or until a certain date?

I guess I could surround the culprit method with a date check and just exit if it is before that date, but was wondering if you guys can suggest a more elegant solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please allow me to post what I finished up doing. Using the information from https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules and http://blog.jiffle.net/post/41125006846/extending-junit-functionality-with-additional I have implemented a Custom Rule with a custom annotation.

Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

  @Retention (value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target( value = { ElementType.METHOD} )
  public @interface IgnoreUntilAfter
  {
    public String value() default "";
  }
```

CustomRule:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class IgnoreForTime
    implements TestRule 
{
  private IgnoreUntilAfter ignoreUntilAfter;

  public String getIgnoreLtdValue()
  {
    return ignoreUntilAfter.value();
  }

  @Override
  public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description)
  {
    return new Statement() 
    {
      @Override
      public void evaluate() throws Throwable 
      {
        ignoreUntilAfter = description.getAnnotation(IgnoreUntilAfter.class);
        if (ignoreUntilAfter != null)
        {        
          LocalDateTime currentTime = new LocalDateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
          if (!currentTime.isAfter(checkAndSetTimeLimit(getIgnoreLtdValue())))
          {
              return;
          }
        }
        base.evaluate();        
      }
    };
  }

  private LocalDateTime checkAndSetTimeLimit(String timeLimit)
  {
    if (timeLimit.isEmpty()) 
    {
      throw new RuntimeException("Please specify the date you want this Ignore to be active until. Ex: 2016-08-24T14:40:19.208 or 2016-08-24");
    }
    return LocalDateTime.parse(timeLimit);
  }
}
```

TestFile:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestIgnoreForTime
{
  @Rule
  public IgnoreForTime timer = new IgnoreForTime();

  @Test
  @IgnoreUntilAfter("2016-08-24T14:40:19.208")
  public void doSomething()
  {
    System.out.println("doSomething");
  }

  @Test
  public void doSomething2()
  {
    System.out.println("doSomething2");
  }

  @Test
  @IgnoreUntilAfter
  public void doSomething3()
  {
    System.out.println("doSomething3");
  }
}
```

Hope this will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are not "good" general answers; I think you might achieve the most with a mix of technical and non-technical solutions; boiling down to a set of rules like:

1. Absolutely minimize the number of @Ignored tests. A flaky test is the worst thing to have in your bucket! Thus: instead of going the easy path and putting @Ignored on some test; you should either: A) delete that test, because it doesn't add substantial value to your test bucket B) spend the time it takes to make the test (and/or your production) code to be **stable**.
2. Use other tooling to track @Ignored tests. For example: create a defect in your tracking system for each and any @Ignored test. And then define timelines how long you will accept such defects to hang around; and policies to deal with them.

In the end, it all boils down to my first recommendation: avoid tests that fail "occasionally".

The intent of tests is to expose regressions in your code base; they exist to provide **value** to you. Things that don't add value should be improved or deleted **as soon as possible**. Keeping them around as is, that's like preferring to walk with a stone in your shoe, because you are too busy to stop and get it out of your shoes.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me, unfortunately I believe your answer does not cover my actual cases where most of the failures come from integration points and as such fixing the issues is not under our control. The tests provide high value and need to exist but we do not accept a red build (just because we think we know what caused it to fail) hence the ignores. We are also talking about a lot of tests (both contract tests and end2ends) so handling failures with tickets (especially against other teams) is way too much overhead.